# printf prints weird characters in C when trying to print a double

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to check a code with another making use of many printf statements in both codes to make sure they are both producing the same numbers at different places throughout. I have run into a problem in one of the codes where my printf statement writes out a strange combination so characters (e.g. X=-Ód½u?É±ÛiR¿ and ÀrÍ²ägS?x©b$ÜñK?).

This is a sample of the code:

```
for (i=0;i<np;i++){
            for (j=0;j<nv;j++){
                    aux1=RASEC*uu[j];
                    aux2=RASEC*vv[j];
                    if((i==456) && (j==5))printf("%g %g %g %g %g\n",uu[j],vv[j],RASEC,aux1,aux2);

            }
}
```

Can anyone help with why this might be occurring and how to fix this?

Many thanks!

Prina

EDIT: Sorry forgot to add that all the numbers I am trying to print out are doubles.

Comment: What are types of variables you are trying to print?

Comment: try %f instead of %g, also try a normal print or cout and see what it gives you.. also if you can give an example would be better.. for example variables 12.44, 23,66 output: #$)(%Q, ^$@$

Comment: Please include minimal and complete program which demonstrates the problem. Code you have given hasn't got enough context to determine the problem.

Comment: Does code include `<stdio.h>`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `%lf` formatting directive for printing doubles.

Also, be careful to match types of values you are printing with the printf format directives. To make sure they match you can cast them to the desired type:

```
printf("%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf\n",
        (double) uu[j],
        (double) vv[j],
        (double) RASEC,
        (double) aux1,
        (double) aux2);
```

Comment: `%f` vs `%lf` makes no difference to `printf` when parameter is of type `float` or `double`.